# MEAN.io aggregated assets location

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

So I've started to use MEAN.io (Mongodb, express, angularJS, nodeJS seed) for my new project, tried to set up the development environment step by step according to http://learn.mean.io/#mean-installation-install-the-mean-cli, and I'm having trouble finding where these global aggregated files(js/css) reside.

As far as I'm understanding, as long as you have set up aggregateAssets(...) in the package, the package js/css files will be automatically minified and aggregated to two files, one for js and another for css? Yet I cannot find where this global aggregated js/css file is, nor does the web browser load the aggregated file(s), instead, each individual js/css for each package, both server and public side is loaded when I run 'grunt', no minification, no aggregation...

So any settings I'm missing?

If MEAN does not put all the js/css files into one, there will be so many static files needed to be loaded(depending on how many packages I have), which means a lot of http request... Isn't that unreasonable?

Answer (score 1):

And I've figured what's going on under the hood... the command 'grunt' runs the server in development environment, and every asset(js/css) file remains what it is, by typing:

```
NODE_ENV=production grunt
```

makes the server run in production mode, and all the minification/concatenation will be done automatically for you and aggregated.css/aggregated.js will be generated.

Comment: Did MEAN.io recently move to gulp? I don't see grunt